# Hibernate: saves object twice into table when connected with an eagerloaded OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, mapping

the class rideSingle is always saved multiple times into the db if a OneToMany relationship is set to eager:

The class which is saved

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class RideSingle  extends HibernateBasicClass{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rideSingle", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<TimedRouteLocation> route;
}
```

The refered class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TimedRouteLocation  extends HibernateBasicClass {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    protected RideSingle rideSingle;
}
```

the hibernate base class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class HibernateBasicClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2253382207065396453L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "generator")
    @JsonProperty
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn = new Date();

    @Version
    private Date lastModified;

    public HibernateBasicClass() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final HibernateBasicClass objWId = (HibernateBasicClass) obj;
        // same id instance
        if (getId() == objWId.getId())
            ;
        // same id content
        if (getId() != null) {
            return getId().equals(objWId.getId());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

There is just one variable, which then is saved by

```
    int i = rideSingleDaox.findAll().size(); // i is 0
    rideSingleDao.saveOrUpdate(this);
    i = rideSingleDaox.findAll().size(); // i is 2
```

The Dao looks like this:

```
public T saveOrUpdate(T object) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
            return object;
}
```

If the rideSingle.route has 2 elements -> rideSingle is put twice in the db. If route has 3 elements, 3 copies of rideSingle are put in the database...

If rideSingle loads the route lazy, this problem does not occure.

```
@Entity
public class RideSingle {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rideSingle", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<TimedRouteLocation> route;
}
```

Does anybody know why this is the case and how i could solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please extend your examples with `@Id` definitions and the code excerpt that causes multiple records to be saved.

Comment: In the example where the entity is saved twice: home many instances of RideSingle and TimedRouteLocation exists in the concrete releationship and how many in total?

Comment: @Mada I added the excerts. Is this helpfull?

Comment: @Ralph In this relationship one rideSingle exists and two TimedRouteLocation. There are no other rideSingle oder timedroutelocation (reseted for the test)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is only a guess:

Try to implement a equals method for both classes.

Comment: @Steve You did remember about it, didn't you?

Comment: @MaDa: what are you talking about?

Comment: @Ralph This could be a good idea! I just had an equal(RideSingle rideSingle) method. Now i added one in HibernateBasicClass. However, it is not helping the problem. Do you have a further hint?

Comment: The equal method seems to be not called by hibernate (tried it in the HibernateBasicClass as well as in the RideSingle). When working with lists this the function works just fine. Do you know which function hibernates uses when saving the cascade?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when calling a list after a persist.
It returned the same object more than once.

I added

.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)

to solve this issue.

The code looks like this:

```
session.createCriteria(clazz)
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
.list()
```